# Dronekit-Python - Stop Mavproxy Downloading Logs

Tags: dronekit-python

I am using Ardupilot in the plane and a Raspberry Pi running dronekit-python at the ground end across 3DR radio - with the Pi not controlling anything, just providing feedback to the pilot when they breach certain things like the boundary of a rectangular geofence (with increasing alarms the further they get out). So I am downloading only a few variables as frequently as I can (or as new data is available).  Can anyone guide me on how to ask mavproxy not to automatically start downloading the whole tlog from the time it is started as I don't need it (other than for occasional debugging - but I can write my own specific log as needed)?

Edit: On digging further it appears to be invoked from lines 985 and 1031 of the mavproxy.py code (call functions set log directories, and write telemetry logs).  Will comment them out and see what happens.

Further Edit:  That works, once I worked out which version of Mavproxy was being loaded.

Gibbo

Answer (score 0):

And from DKPY2 (just released) there is no MAVProxy dependency, so this should no longer be an issue.